# Set JSON object to a Const on material UI Select component React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am getting an JSON array of objects from a API call which is respectively :

```
[
   {
      "staffTypeID":103,
      "staffType":"3",
      "staffPermissionType":"Regular",
      "staffRoleID":31,
      "staffRole":"Sales_Regular"
   },
   {
      "staffTypeID":52,
      "staffType":"1",
      "staffPermissionType":"Admin",
      "staffRoleID":11,
      "staffRole":"Admin"
   }
]
```

I am using Formik Material UI to list it on a Select, and the code as follows:

```
<Field name="StaffType" label="Staff Type"  component={Select}
                                       options={Object.keys(StaffTypes).map((StaffType) =>
({value: StaffTypes[StaffTypes].staffTypeID, label: StaffTypes[StaffTypes].staffRole}))}/>
```

Also I have a constant to assign Value:

```
const [staff,setStaff]=useState('');
```

I need to set the value of the json Object to the staff const by selecting in the dropdown. By clicking in the Select dropdown the staff constant should be assigned to

```
 {
    "staffTypeID":103,
    "staffType":"3",
    "staffPermissionType":"Regular",
    "staffRoleID":31,
    "staffRole":"Sales_Regular"
 }
```

So I can use the the code else as `<h2>{staff.staffPermissionType.toUpperCase()}</h2>`

can Anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Formik, but was able to do what I think you're trying to do on [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-formik-components-1dmgx?file=/src/RegistrationForm.jsx:0-1163).

The Formik component provides the current form values to the child component, so you don't need useState at all.

Here's the relevant part:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import { Select } from "material-ui-formik-components/Select";

const StaffTypes = [
  {
    staffTypeID: 103,
    staffType: "3",
    staffPermissionType: "Regular",
    staffRoleID: 31,
    staffRole: "Sales_Regular"
  },
  {
    staffTypeID: 52,
    staffType: "1",
    staffPermissionType: "Admin",
    staffRoleID: 11,
    staffRole: "Admin"
  }
];

const FormCmp = ({ values, handleChange }) => {
  // get the currently selected StaffType id
  const staffRoleID = (values || {}).StaffType;

  // look up the item in the options array
  const staffType = StaffTypes.find(x => x.staffRoleID === staffRoleID);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* display the selected staffRole */}
      <h1>{staffType && staffType.staffRole}</h1>
      <Form>
        <Field
          name="StaffType"
          label="Staff Type"
          options={StaffTypes.map(entry => ({
            value: entry.staffRoleID,
            label: entry.staffRole
          }))}
          component={Select}
        />
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

function StaffTypeForm() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik initialValues={{ StaffType: StaffTypes[0].staffRoleID }}>
        {FormCmp}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StaffTypeForm;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation @ray hatfield, but when am using the onchange function I am unable to set the value for the select component. When I click the selected value the onchange handler is changing the heading, still the select field is empty

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-formik-components This is the npm module I was using for Formik and Material UI. Hope this could help.

Comment: See updated answer; now provides a `value` to the select.

Comment: Getting the following error when doing so, `Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type hidden to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).`

Comment: Updated again to default the value to an empty string.

Comment: Because of using formik, I cant define value myself, https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-formik-components. Am new to react as I followed the above documentation.

Comment: Figured out by manually assigning the values for the components. working fine, Not a good practice though, Should Figure out a right way and update the answer. Thanks for help. <3

Comment: Tinkered with Formik's codesandbox demo and I think I got it to do what you're trying to do. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Ray! Ill check on it! The idea i was using was to set the value for the initial values on change. That helped me! Ill try on like the answer